# XML to string (C#)

Tags: c#, xml, c#-4.0, rss

I have a XML loaded from a URL like this:

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();
client.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;

try
{
    string reply = client.DownloadString("http://Example.com/somefile.xml");
    label1.Text = reply;
}
catch
{
    label1.Text = "FAILED";

}
```

That XML belongs to a RSS Feed. I want that label1.Text shows just the titles of that XML. How can I achieve that?

Example of label1.Text

```
This is my first title    -    This is my 2nd title    -    And this is my last title
```

Comment: Are you asking how to parse data from XML?  Something like Linq To XML?

Comment: All titles? OR just title of the channel?

Comment: Your URL is publicly accessible. Changed it to `http://example.com/somefile.xml`

Comment: Is Title an `attribute` or `element` of the XML?

Comment: @Habib : Is it a problem that the OP posted a URL to a publicly available resources?

Comment: @spender, now that you said it, I think it shouldn't be. *(coming from this [post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/226793/should-we-approve-edits-that-just-change-commercial-links-to-example-com))*. If you think that is not the right thing to do then I or you can revert it back

Comment: Just the titles from the XML (not the channel title, the news title, the rss is from a newspaper).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can load your XML into an XmlDocument and then use XPath to Get the value of each node you're targeting.

> ```
>        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
>        doc.LoadXml(reply);
>        XmlNodeList nodes = doc.SelectNodes("//NodeToSelect");
>
>        foreach (XmlNode node in nodes)
>        {
>            //If the value you want is the content of the node
>            label1.Text = node.InnerText; 
>            //If the value you want is an attribute of the node
>            label1.Text = node.Attributes["AttibuteName"].Value; 
>        }
> ```

If you are not familiar with XPath you can always check here :
http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_syntax.asp

Comment: I got every title in a new line, and I want them one next to another, I tied `label1.Text.Replace(Environment.NewLine, " - ");` but it doesn't work. Do you know what can I do?

Comment: node.InnerText or node.Attribute[""].Value return a simple string. If you want to split it by some dash, try to append your dash each time you're appending a new value to your label.

At the end you’ll only have to remove the last dash like this:
label1.text = label1.Text.TrimEnd('-');

Answer (score 1):

```
var xml= XElement.Parse(reply);
label1.Text = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, xml
.Descendants()
.Where (x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.Value))
.Select(x=> string.Format("{0}: {1}", x.Name, x.Value))
.ToArray());
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to parse the RSS XML manually to get the title. Here is some sample code for your reference:

```
private static List<FeedsItem> ParseFeeds(string feedsXml)
{
    XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Parse(feedsXml);
    XNamespace xmlns = "http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom";

    var items = from entry in xDoc.Descendants(xmlns + "entry")
                select new FeedsItem
                {
                    Id = (string)entry.Element(xmlns + "id").Value,
                    Title = (string)entry.Element(xmlns + "title").Value,
                    AlternateLink = (string)entry.Descendants(xmlns + "link").Where(link => link.Attribute("rel").Value == "alternate").First().Attribute("href").Value
                };

    Console.WriteLine("Count = {0}", items.Count());
    foreach(var i in items)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(i);
    }

    return null;
}
```